# Debian 10 32-bit ior any Linux) install on Dell Venue 11 Pro

Tags: linux, boot, debian, installation, grub

I was hoping that I could get some assistance with a little problem I've been having while attempting to install 32-bit Debian 10 on a [Dell Venue Pro 11 tablet](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=Venue%2011%20Pro%205000&sort=relevancy&f:iuxType=[Manuals%20%26%20Documentation]&f:product1Facet=[Tablets]&f:langFacet=[en]).

However the only real issue with it was that the update from Windows 8 to 10 didn't work right, and now I would like to just boot the device off a thumb drive and install Linux, which would have been my end goal anyway. Currently the only distro I can get to boot at all is Debian's 32 bit disc image. I can even get as far as installing the grub boot loader, but this is where it fails.

I cannot seem to find anyone else with this issue, and I am finding it odd that the tablet will only boot with Debian.

If anyone can help at all, it would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Which variant of Dell Venue Pro do you have?   (I have the 7139, but I think there is also an atom based 5130 series which is even harder to make work)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Venue 11 Pro, and got it working with Ubuntu 16.04.  Assuming you are taking aout the "7139" this device is a pain in the neck to get working properly, but it is possible.   I get a lot of joy out of mine.

I do note that it is VERY PICKY about what is compiled into the kernel - I needed to lock it in to 4.10.0-42-generic to get all the functionality. FWIW, I have a note that the install was done using Ubuntu 16.04.02 (64 bit) in June 2017. Depending on the exact version you have, you may also need to replace the wireless module - last time I looked - and I spent a lot of time on it - there is no practical way to get the Atheros wireless module working - If your system does not come with an Intel WIFI card, save yourself a lot of hassle and buy one off EBAY.

I note that my system is using UEFI to boot, and wonder if the UEFI/legacy mode and/or 32 bit UEFI requirement is playing into your problems.

Scratching way back, I seem to recall that some Venue 11 (pros?) came with an Atom CPU.  If yours is one of these, you may have other difficulties because the Atom based systems require a 32 bit boot loader (but are otherwise a 64 bit system).  I think making this work is "a bridge to far" but try googling "Linux x65 on 32-bit UEFI" - some people have had some success.   Not sure if you can bypass this issue by just installing a 32 bit (ie i386 rather then x86) variant of your preferred distro.

The appropriate entry from my lspci -v is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 7c-7a-91-ff-ff-de-c1-82
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Hey, I'm looking to buy an intel wifi card for my V11 pro, but I'm not sure which ones are compatible. Would you happen to know?

Comment: @Erik I would imagine any that have the appropriate form factor and drivers, which would be most if not all of them.  I'll only get to fire mine up next Tuesday (its at Office, I'm not), but I'll endeavour to post the WIFI model in mine then.   From memory though it comes with either the Intel cards (which work) or the Atheros ones (which didn't, requiring support for GPIO which was not available).

Comment: Thanks! I did a bit of digging around on some forums and what you say confirms what I have been looking at. I ended up getting the same wifi card listed in the tablet specs on Dell's website (Intel® 7260AC Dual-Band 2x2).

Comment: I just opened mine up and it turns out this card does not fit, unfortunately. I should have done my research first to see what kind of slot it is. Hoping to hear from you on Tuesday!

Comment: @erik not sure why yours does not fit - I've added the specs from my system above.  Care to tell us which model Venue11 you are using and the details of your card - bonus for pictures?

Comment: I'm using a 5130. The wifi card is not replaceable, I'm instead trying to add it to the WWAN card slot but it doesn't seem to be m.2. However, I managed to get the Atheros card working, so I'm going to add a comment for reference sake. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, and I can't help you unfortunately, but I was able to install Manjaro 32 on a 5130 of mine that was running Windows 10 initially. However, there are problems with wifi working out of the box and many people have been trying to get it to work. I came across the solution, and I think it's a good idea to put it here since you will probably need it later on.

Download the [ath6kl](https://github.com/qca/ath6kl-firmware) driver and then extract the `hw3.0` and `hw1.3` folders and place it in `/lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6004/` overriding the folders that may already be there. That worked well enough for me.

I found the solution from [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187204&page=9&p=13103443#post13103443) Ubuntu forum post, and it also says the following:

> Also needed is to tell the ath6kl driver that it can support the chip with SDIO id 0271:0418. It is a line like:
>
> {SDIO_DEVICE(MANUFACTURER_CODE, (MANUFACTURER_ID_AR6004_BASE | 0x18))},
>
> you have to add to the struct "static const struct sdio_device_id ath6kl_sdio_devices[]" in the file sdio.c of the ath6kl driver so it will handle the device.

However, I did not need to do this.

Comment: As you said, not an answer (so I should downvote this).  On the other hand, I'm impressed that you got a managed to get the Atheros device working - well done.   (I should upvote for this!)  I had 0 luck trying the above things on my older system - granted some years ago.   It does seem that my older model was a different one as I distinctly remember popping off the antennas and putting in a new card, but yours does seem to be part of the mainboard after googling the spec.